# Why my microphone does not works as well?

Tags: java

I want to make a microphone that writes to a file but the file is empty. I don't understand why.

```
public void recordSound () throws IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
  // Assume that the TargetDataLine, line, has already
  // been obtained and opened.
  AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, true);
  TargetDataLine line = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
  ByteArrayOutputStream out  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  int numBytesRead;
  byte[] data = new byte[line.getBufferSize() / 5];

  // Begin audio capture.
  line.start();
  // Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
  numBytesRead =  line.read(data, 0, data.length);
  // Save this chunk of data.
  out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
  out.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("./audio.wav"));
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  line.stop();
  line.close(); }
```

Comment: Close your FileOutputStream.  Or, even better, [let Java do it for you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: I did it. Does not work

Comment: Your code has other issues.  It’s unlikely one `read` call will get all of your audio data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the line first

```
line.open(line.getFormat());
line.start();
```